# C++ File Selection Window

Tags: c++, linux, visual-c++

Case: I have several text file, and I need have a interface to choose them into my program.
Here is the code that I have write

```
using namespace std;
vector<string> strings;

ifstream file("TestingRead.txt");
std::string str;
string myArray[5];

while (std::getline(file, str, ','))
{

    cout << str << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i <= 4; i++) {
        myArray[i] = str;
    }
    strings.push_back(str);
}
```

Please take a look at : ifstream file("TestingRead.txt");
Is it anyway to replace the hard code method ?? May be a file selector window ? And my OS is running at Linux

Comment: `visual-c++` and `linux`?

Comment: I run at raspb-pi , so I work on visual c++ and convert the cpp file

Comment: @JackdonChew Do you choose file just single time (like on startup) or you  should be able to choose between files more than once?

Comment: @CaptainTrunky I want choose file just on startup only ~ Now the method I done is using hardcode the directory to TestingRead.txt

Answer (score 0):

You should have a look at a GUI library, such as Gtk+, Qt, wxWidget or etc. For example, [`GtkFileChooserDialog`](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkFileChooserDialog.html) is what you want in Gtk+.

Comment: @JackdonChew of course: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/gtk-getting-started.html

Comment: @JackdonChew If you want to choose gtk+, you can use its C++-style interface, [gtkmm](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/stable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en), instead of raw gtk+.

Comment: wow ... that totally a new area that I never touch before ... Is it user friendly for beginner? Thanks very much for your opinion

Comment: @JackdonChew I think you should be used to C or C++ to learn those GUI libraries. Btw, please choose my answer if it is helpful :)

Comment: To be honest, I am searching for something to replace that line
ifstream file("TestingRead.txt");
I searching for something may be like 
String A;
A = openfilewindow();
ifstream file(A);

Comment: So I just want a window, that will allow user to choose a file name, and put it into a string, then the other execution still the same

Comment: @JackdonChew that's why file selection window such as `GtkFileChooserDialog` exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to open a file just once, it might be easier to code and use just command-line arguments:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main (int argc, char* argv[]) {
  if (argc < 2) {
    std::cerr << "Provide filepath: ./my_program file_name" << std::endl;
    return 1;
  }

  const std::string file_to_open (argv[1]);

  std::ifstream file (file_to_open.c_str());

  //  do some awesome stuff here

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: namespace "std" has no member "err"

Comment: @JackdonChew My mistake. It must be 'cerr'. The code is fixed. Thanks.